# React router update parent state from children class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Suppose my routes as below:

```
<Route name="base" path="/" component={Base}>
  <Route name="A" path="/a" component={A}></Route>
</Route>
```

the `Base` class and `A` class as below:

```
var Base = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {current: 1}
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.state.current}</div>
      <div>{this.props.children}</div>
    );
  }
});


var A = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount() {
    // how to set base class state
    // 
  },
  render() {
     ....
  }
});
```

I want to set or update the `Base(this.state.current)` state from the `A`'s `componentDidMount` method, what should I do at the scene.

Comment: Are you open to using a state management solution such as redux or mobx? Any particular constraints in mind?

Comment: Not use the state management solution, just in simply react router class. @bebraw

Comment: Ok, no idea them. By the looks of it react-router API doesn't provide easy access to parent so this is going to be tough to solve without.

Comment: Well, maybe I should import the state management,  thanks so much. @bebraw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work, you could end up with something like this:

```
var Base = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {current: 1}
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.state.current}</div>
      <div>{this.props.children}</div>
      <div>{this.props.demo}</div>
    );
  }
});

export default connect(state => ({
  demo: state.demo
}))(Base);

---

var A = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount() {
    // how to set base class state
    //

    this.props.setDemo('demo');
  },
  render() {
     ....
  }
});

export default connect(() => ({}), {
  setDemo
});
```

This solution is based on [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) and [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux), but it should be possible to adapt it to other systems. The idea is the same.

If you go with Redux, you'll need to implement an action and a reducer matching semantics above.